# References on Definiteness

Tags: semantics, reference-request, definiteness

Does anybody happen to know of any good and fairly readily-available surveys of the language-specific semantics of definiteness cross-linguistically? Specifically, I'm interested in all the various ways of defining definiteness in terms of which things are grammatically definite in a given language and which aren't. E.g. how English and Greek have somewhat different criteria for applying the definite and indefinite articles.

Answer (score 2):

Lyons, Christopher. 1999. [Definiteness](http://www.cambridge.org/gb/knowledge/isbn/item1137305/?site_locale=en_GB). Cambridge: CUP.

Dryer, Matthew S. 2011. Definite Articles. In: Dryer, Matthew S. & Haspelmath, Martin (eds.)
The World Atlas of Language Structures Online. Munich: Max Planck Digital Library, chapter 37.
Available online at http://wals.info/chapter/37 Accessed on 2012-03-02.

In Dryer's paper, he understands a definite article as "a morpheme which accompanies nouns and which codes definiteness or specificity."